# Intel pin: Instrumentate running process

Tags: c++, x86, intel, instrumentation, intel-pin

I created a simple pin tool that dumps any win32 CreateFileW calls. It works fine, but when i try to attach it to an already running process, the process simply terminates. Tried with several applications (notepad, wordpad, internet explorer), same result. This is the command i use:

```
.\pin -pid 8804 -t dumpfile.dll
```

I got a tip to try and turn off multi-threading like this:

```
.\pin -mt 0 -pid 8804 -t dumpfile.dll
```

but it did not help. Also tried with another, out of the box pintool, didn't work either, so the problem is not in my pintool. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add an answer as to your question and then accept it rather than just editing the question to add the solution you've discovered..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, today i had some time on my hands to research this problem again. Tested with a console application launched from cmd, and before shutting down, it actually dumped an error message, the .dll (the pin tool) was not found...

So when running pin you actually have to specify the full path to your pin tool, or the path relative to the instrumentated binary's location.

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am for this. This question and answer must be upvoted even more.